# Drawing complications separately using WatchFaceKotlin Wear OS sample

Tags: kotlin, wear-os

First off, I am using the Google Wear OS sample called [WatchFaceKotlin](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin).

The sample provided draws all of the complications at once.
I have added a background complication so that users can customize the background with perhaps a weather image or something more personal. Problem is that the background complication is drawn so bright that the complications in front of the image can no longer be seen. I want to use drawARGB() in front of the background complication and let the user decide on the background brightness with a slider in the settings.
I cant seem to find a place to do this since all complications are drawn at once and adding the drawARGB() after that darkens all complications. Is there a way to split the complications using the new API's so that I can draw the background, then the drawARGB(), and then the smaller complications? Here is where I am thinking that something could possibly be done but there is something that I am missing since this way does not work correctly

In the AnalogWatchCanvasRenderer.kt

```
    // ----- All drawing functions -----
private fun drawComplications(canvas: Canvas, zonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime) {
    for ((_, complication) in complicationSlotsManager.complicationSlots) {
        if (complication.enabled) {
            complication.render(canvas, zonedDateTime, renderParameters)
            canvas.drawARGB(watchFaceData.brightnessFractionDefault.brightnessFraction.toInt(),0,0,0)
        }
    }
}
```

There must be a way to only draw a specific complication instead of using complication.render and drawing them all at once. Any thoughts? Thanks for any attempt to help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a supported feature, so you are probably out of luck.  You might want to raise a request for this at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/wear-watchface#feedback

Comment: Would it make sense to draw the background as part of the watchface instead?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question about drawing the background as part of the watchface. Since the background would be a complication, I'm not sure there is another place that it can be drawn other than with the other complications since it has to use ComplicationSlot.createBackgroundComplicationSlotBuilder()

Comment: Since you are writing the watchface also, can you put this specific logic into the watchface? Draw it yourself instead of using a complication for it.  This isn't something the current implementation is designed to handle as it stands. Maybe you can't.

Comment: Ahh, I am not providing the background images. They would be coming from external complication providers so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can your watchface use the complication data and render yourself?

Comment: As of right now, no. I have only made a couple changes to the default template. I am working on converting from an older java based watchface 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lancelinksp.functional

Comment: I did end up creating a [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233045834) for this functionality at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/wear-watchface#feedback

Comment: @lancelinksp Can you share the issue link, so we can star it?

Comment: @LouisCAD Here is the link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233045834. I is in the comment above though if you click the word request. Looks like it has already been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition when calling render, where you check the id or the type of the slot, and draw a darkening color just after drawing the slot.

This is the kind of condition that can help you make it work:

```
if (complication.boundsType == ComplicationSlotBoundsType.BACKGROUND) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I attempted that approach by checking the id in the if statement where render is called but although it does check for the id, all complications are still drawn when calling complication.render(canvas, zonedDateTime, renderParameters)

Comment: You probably render it twice or more. I personally have conditioned complications rendering in my Watch Face app, and it works fine.

Comment: I think it renders almost constantly while the face is awake. I have some logging I added and it seems pretty constant. Mind sharing how you are handling the conditions to be able to draw them separately if you are using the same template?

Comment: Too complicated to share my code, but I'm 100% sure you can figure it out yourself and self-answer if my answer isn't sufficient for you.

Comment: I did get this working, just for example if you put it in your answer I will mark it as correct. I did something similar to ... if (complication.boundsType == ComplicationSlotBoundsType.BACKGROUND) { ... }

Comment: Added the snippet, finally!